# After adding any new Stored Procedure in EDMX file - getting reference or namespace not found error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting two below errors.after adding a new procedure to the EDMX.

1. The type or namespace name 'ObjectResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. The type or namespace name 'Object' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you show us the code you've added?

Comment: now problem solved.thanks for your reply.it's working fine now. after replacing using System.Data.Objects; with using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects and adding the reference System.Data.Entity.dll.

Comment: Would you please answer your own question? Other visitors of this site might run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove using `System.Data.Objects` and put `using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses`.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
//using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Linq;
```